# Unit testing CanDeactiveGuard and ModalDialogService behind it

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got a `CanDeactiveGuard` that's working just fine. I'm writing unit tests and they're working except for one where I want to `callThrough` and launch the Modal Dialog component that prompts the user to save. The `openConfirmDialog()` method is in the Guard but it calls a service to launch the modal. The service is the code I want executed.

So, there's the Guard class and the `ModalDialogService` that is responsible for launching the modal. Is it realistic to execute the code in `ModalDialogService` from a method in the Guard? Or should I be testing the service separately?

Here's the guard spec file:

```
class MockGuardComponent implements ComponentCanDeactivate {
  // Set this value to the value you want to mock being returned from 
GuardedComponent
  returnValue: boolean | Observable<boolean>;

  canDeactivate(): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    return this.returnValue;
  }
}

describe('PendingChangesGuard', () => {
  let mockGuardComponent: MockGuardComponent;
  let service: PendingChangesGuard;
  let dialogService: ModalDialogService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ModalDialogComponent],
      providers: [
        PendingChangesGuard,
        MockGuardComponent,
        Overlay,
        ModalDialogService,
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
    }).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [ModalDialogComponent],
      },
    });
    service = TestBed.get(PendingChangesGuard);
    dialogService = TestBed.get(ModalDialogService);
    mockGuardComponent = TestBed.get(MockGuardComponent);
  });

  it('should expect service to instantiate', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('can route if unguarded -- form is not dirty', () => {
    mockGuardComponent.returnValue = true;
    expect(service.canDeactivate(mockGuardComponent)).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('cannot route if guarded -- form is dirty', () => {
// *** Here is where I'm trying to execute the openConfirmDialog() 
method that creates a modal
    spyOn(service, 'openConfirmDialog').and.callThrough();
    mockGuardComponent.returnValue = false;
    expect(service.canDeactivate(mockGuardComponent)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(service.openConfirmDialog).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('will route if guarded and user accepted the dialog and 
confirmed', () => {
    // Mock the behavior of the Component
    const subject$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    mockGuardComponent.returnValue = subject$.asObservable();
    const canDeactivate$ = <Observable<boolean>>(
      service.canDeactivate(mockGuardComponent)
    );
    canDeactivate$.subscribe((deactivate) => {
      // This is the real test
      expect(deactivate).toBeTruthy();
    });
    // Emulate the accept action
    subject$.next(true);
  });

  it('will not route if guarded and user rejected the dialog', () => {
    // Mock the behavior of the MockGuardedComponent
    const subject$ = new Subject<boolean>();
    mockGuardComponent.returnValue = subject$.asObservable();
    const canDeactivate$ = <Observable<boolean>>(
      service.canDeactivate(mockGuardComponent)
    );
    canDeactivate$.subscribe((deactivate) => {
      // this is the real test
      expect(deactivate).toBeFalsy();
    });
    // Emulate the reject
    subject$.next(false);
  });
});
```

So, you can see it's the 2nd test where I'm trying to call right through the *openConfirmDialog()* method and have it launch the modal.

And here's the *ModalDialogService* class:

```
export class ModalDialogService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private readonly document: Document,
    private readonly viewportRuler: ViewportRuler,
    private readonly injector: Injector,
    private readonly overlay: Overlay
  ) {}

  public open<T, D>(
    component: ComponentType<T>,
    config: ModalDialogConfig<D> = {}
  ): ModalDialogRef<T> {
    // Override default configuration
    const dialogConfig = { ...DEFAULT_CONFIG, ...config };

    // Returns an OverlayRef which is a PortalHost
    const overlayRef = this.createOverlay(dialogConfig);

    // Instantiate remote control
    const dialogRef = new ModalDialogRef<T>(overlayRef);
    dialogRef.instance = this.attachDialogContainer(
      component,
      overlayRef,
      dialogConfig,
      dialogRef
    );

    if (dialogConfig.hasBackdrop && dialogConfig.closeOnBackdropClick) 
    {
      overlayRef.backdropClick().subscribe(() => dialogRef.close());
    }

    return dialogRef;
  }

  private createOverlay(config: ModalDialogConfig): OverlayRef {
     const overlayConfig = this.getOverlayConfig(config);
    return this.overlay.create(overlayConfig);
  }

  private attachDialogContainer<T>(
    component: ComponentType<T>,
    overlayRef: OverlayRef,
    config: ModalDialogConfig,
    dialogRef: ModalDialogRef<T>
  ): T {
    const injector = this.createInjector(config, dialogRef);
    const containerPortal = new ComponentPortal(component, undefined, 
injector);
    const containerRef: ComponentRef<T> = 
overlayRef.attach(containerPortal);

    return containerRef.instance;
  }

  private createInjector<T, D>(
    config: ModalDialogConfig<D>,
    dialogRef: ModalDialogRef<T>
  ): PortalInjector {
    const injectionTokens = new WeakMap();
    injectionTokens.set(ModalDialogRef, dialogRef);
    injectionTokens.set(MODAL_DIALOG_DATA, config.data || null);

    return new PortalInjector(this.injector, injectionTokens);
  }

  private getOverlayConfig(config: ModalDialogConfig): OverlayConfig {
    const positionStrategy = this.overlay
      .position()
      .global()
      .centerHorizontally()
      .centerVertically();

    const overlayConfig = new OverlayConfig({
      hasBackdrop: config.hasBackdrop,
      backdropClass: config.backdropClass,
      panelClass: config.panelClass,
      disposeOnNavigation: config.closeOnNavigation,
      scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.block(),
      positionStrategy,
    });

    return overlayConfig;
  }
}
```

Since the `openConfirmDialog()` method isn't actually executing the code in the `ModalDialogService` then I must have to test that separately, correct? And, if that's the case, do I need to mock all the objects I need to create a dialog, i.e. `OverlayRef, ModalDialogConfig, ModalDialogRef`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding :-
Yes you have to create a test case for **ModalDialogService** you are doing unit testing. so every file must have there test file and corresponding test cases.

As for the below test case below line and the **ModalDialogService** in provider. You have imported the service not the mock of that service (like we do this providers:[{ provide:ModalDialogService , useValue: {yourMockvalues related to service} }] ).

```
dialogService = TestBed.get(ModalDialogService);
```

// You are using a spy , that will not hit the service function as you need that thing in the expect part too.

so when you **spy on a method** that actual methodis not called.

```
 it('cannot route if guarded -- form is dirty', () => {
// *** Here is where I'm trying to execute the openConfirmDialog() 
method that creates a modal
    spyOn(service, 'openConfirmDialog').and.callThrough(); // not actual will hit
    mockGuardComponent.returnValue = false;
    expect(service.canDeactivate(mockGuardComponent)).toBeFalsy();
    expect(service.openConfirmDialog).toHaveBeenCalled(); // to use in inspect you need to spy. 
  });
```

It's like you have tested a part that on deactivate 'openConfirmDialog' thing will be called.
and there will be a **other test case** what happens when you call  'openConfirmDialog'.

**Mock only the methods/properties that are being used in that component.**.

Like  ModalDialogService can have 5 methods but in PendingChangesGuard you have used only 2 method of ModalDialogService .

So In PendingChangesGuard  , just mock 2 method of ModalDialogService.

```
providers:[{ provide:ModalDialogService , useValue: {open: jasmine.createSpy('open')} }]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've decided that it's better to test the service in its own spec file and I created a simple unit test using the following code:

```
it('should open a modal dialog', () => {
    spyOn(modalDialogService, 'open').and.callThrough();
    modalDialogService.open(ModalDialogComponent, null);
    expect(modalDialogService.open).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

I didn't have to mock any of the dependencies of the *ModalDialogService*, I only needed to pass in the *ModalDialogComponent* to the *open* method to trigger the code getting unit tested.